# getting the src value of an img and give it another element as background image

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

So I was trying to get the img src of one element and give it to another element as background image with jQuery.

```
jQuery(function() {
            var event_image = jQuery('.evo_event_main_img').attr('src');
            jQuery(".ret_event_header").css("background-image", "url('" + event_image + "')");
        });
```

Now what the .ret_event_header element gets is:

```
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTUwMCA4MjUiIHdpZHRoPSIxNTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjgyNSIgZGF0YS11PSJodHRwcyUzQSUyRiUyRmNtcy5yZXRhcnVzLmNvbSUyRndwLWNvbnRlbnQlMkZ1cGxvYWRzJTJGMjAyMCUyRjA5JTJGaGVhZGVyNGIuanBnIiBkYXRhLXc9IjE1MDAiIGRhdGEtaD0iODI1IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjwvc3ZnPg==);
```

HTML:

```
<img class="evo_event_main_img" src="https://img.link/header4b.jpg" data-spai="1" data-spai-upd="700">

<div class="ret_event_header et_pb_section et_pb_section_0 ret_padding_100-0 et_pb_with_background et_section_regular">
```

When pasting that code in the browser console the right path gets shown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML as well. OR post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
 thanks

Comment: sorry, i just added the relevant HTML.

Comment: The `src` attribute shows the URL "https://img.link/header4b.jpg", and the code changes that to something beginning with "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2Zy..."? That's quite odd...

Comment: yes i know. i don't really understand that...

Comment: is your `div` is always empty like this show here with no content ? Also that is weird behavious - are you sure the `src` is actual URL and not `base64` encoded ? Can you `console.log(event_image )` and what shows up in the console

Comment: no the `div` is full of other elements so I didn't copy them in. When using `console.log(event_image)` the same svg gets put out: `data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTUwMCA4MjUiIHdpZHRoPSIxNTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjgyNSIgZGF0YS11PSJodHRwcyUzQSUyRiUyRmNtcy5yZXRhcnVzLmNvbSUyRndwLWNvbnRlbnQlMkZ1cGxvYWRzJTJGMjAyMCUyRjA5JTJGaGVhZGVyNGIuanBnIiBkYXRhLXc9IjE1MDAiIGRhdGEtaD0iODI1IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjwvc3ZnPg==`

Comment: @Alex ahh your src is an `SVG` - that might be causing the issue since its not like a `jpg` or `png` img.